# SQL Query to show Customer Name and Multiple Invoice number (Crystal Report)

Tags: crystal-reports

I am currently stuck with SQL Query as i am doing a report on Crystal Report.
I have a bunch of Customer Names and Invoice numbers.

Result i am getting now on crystal report:
[Result i am getting now on crystal report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wG9e.png)

I want to do a result like this
[I want to do a result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnOBs.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use Insert, Group... to group the report by customer. 
Either show the customer info only in the group header or if you simply wish to suppress repeating customer info in the detail section, right-click those fields, select Format Field, go to 'Common' tab, and turn on the option of 'Suppress if Duplicate'

See image: https://www.screencast.com/t/Njf8gNa7M4